# Checking if an asset exists

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I want to check if an asset already exists before creating a new one. I'm currently using the following code:

```py
def asset_exists(asset_id: str) -> bool:
    """Check the existence of the asset"""
    try:
        ee.data.getAsset(asset_id)
    except ee.EEException:
        exists = False
    else:
        exists = True
    return exists
```

Is there another method that would be more elegant and improve compactness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I din't find a better way so I coded it in [`geetools`](https://gee-tools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) plugin lib.

Using the `Asset` object, on can call the `exists` methods directly from it as:

```py
import ee, geetools

asset = ee.Asset("projects/bar/assets/foo")
asset.exists()
```

The method can also raise an error on failure if needed:

```py
import ee, geetools

asset = ee.Asset("projects/bar/assets/foo")
asset.exists(raised=True)
```

See more information in [`Asset` documentation page](https://gee-tools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/autoapi/geetools/Asset/index.html#geetools.Asset.Asset.exists).